# Sax error on hero

Tags: java, android

I'm using sax parser to get xml data, the below code is causing my app to crash.

```
    try {
        url = new URL("The URL");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   // RssFeed feed = null;
    try {
        feed = RssReader.read(url);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Looks like it is crashing at `feed = RssReader.read(url);` It works fine on my evo but when I install it on my hero the below error occurs

```
04-28 15:57:53.458: E/AndroidRuntime(2749): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught  exception
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mlgw.mlgwapp/com.mlgw.mlgwapp.TipsActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2411)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:648)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:379)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:874)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2068)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1679)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1697)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1646)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at nl.matshofman.saxrssreader.RssHandler.endElement(RssHandler.java:67)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.endElement(ExpatParser.java:159)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.append(Native Method)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:506)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:467)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:329)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:286)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at nl.matshofman.saxrssreader.RssReader.read(RssReader.java:43)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at com.mlgw.mlgwapp.TipsActivity.onCreate(TipsActivity.java:57)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-28 15:57:53.589: E/AndroidRuntime(2749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
```

Please Help!!

Here is my RssHandler class

```
package nl.matshofman.saxrssreader;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class RssHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private RssFeed rssFeed;
private RssItem rssItem;
private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

@Override
public void startDocument() {
    rssFeed = new RssFeed();
}

/**
 * Return the parsed RssFeed with it's RssItems
 * @return
 */
public RssFeed getResult() {
    return rssFeed;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if(qName.equals("item") && rssFeed != null) {
        rssItem = new RssItem();
        rssItem.setFeed(rssFeed);
        rssFeed.addRssItem(rssItem);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
    stringBuilder.append(ch, start, length);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {

    if(rssFeed != null && rssItem == null) {
        // Parse feed properties

        try {
            String methodName = "set" + qName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + qName.substring(1);
            Method method = rssFeed.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
            method.invoke(rssFeed, stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }

    } else if (rssItem != null) {
        // Parse item properties

        try {
            if(qName.equals("content:encoded")) 
                qName = "content";
            String methodName = "set" + qName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + qName.substring(1);
            Method method = rssItem.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
            method.invoke(rssItem, stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

}
ok I added that now there is this

```
04-28 18:49:35.189: E/AndroidRuntime(3780): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mlgw.mlgwapp/com.mlgw.mlgwapp.TipsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2411)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:648)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:320)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:379)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:874)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2068)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1679)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1697)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:221)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at com.mlgw.mlgwapp.TipsActivity.onCreate(TipsActivity.java:71)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
04-28 18:49:35.328: E/AndroidRuntime(3780):     ... 30 more
```

Now seems to have somethig to do with the round function I'm using.

Comment: You'll need to post the code for your RssHandler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace tells you the cause of the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1646)
     at nl.matshofman.saxrssreader.RssHandler.endElement(RssHandler.java:67)
```

The actual error happens in `java.lang.String.substring()` which is not your code so you can't fix anything there. But the next line tells you where `substring` was called. `RssHandler.java` in line 67, in method `endElement`

That should be:

```
String methodName = "set" + qName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + qName.substring(1)
```

String indexes are their characters so you access `qName` although it is empty and you can't build a substring from just the first character or starting after the first character.

To prevent the crash you can do

```
if (qName != null && qName.length() > 0) {
    String methodName = "set" + qName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + qName.substring(1);
    Method method = rssFeed.getClass().getMethod(methodName, String.class);
    method.invoke(rssFeed, stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

and you should have a look at the XML and find out why there is a qName that does not fit the expected format.

Also `localName` might be better to check since the qualified name of  `<xsl:template />` is `xsl:template` while the local name is just `template`.